# Inline SVG - how to set background-image with style attribute (in Angular 5)

Tags: css, svg, angular5

I want to create a table which displays graphs. Inside each row I want to show a polyline graph, which is displayed based on data from the table cells.
I've decided to achieve that by creating graph with SVG and setting it as background-image for each row. I have created the SVG but I can not figure it out how to set it as background-image (by writing styles="background-image: url(...);", if I define css styles inside class (and set it to table row) it works fine, but it's not what I want because I need different graph for each row).

My code:

**index.component.ts:**

```
let svgBackgrounds = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none' class='svg-graph' viewBox='0 0 1400 100'><style type='text/css'>.base-line{ fill: none; stroke: rgb(116, 96, 238); stroke-width: 3px; }.base-body{ fill: rgba(116, 96, 238, .1); }</style><g class='graph'><polyline class='base-line' points='0,50 100,10 200,50 300,70 400,40 500,20 600,60 700,70 800,80 900,20 1000,40 1100,70 1200,10 '></polyline><polyline class='base-body' points='0,100 0,50 100,10 200,50 300,70 400,40 500,20 600,60 700,70 800,80 900,20 1000,40 1100,70 1200,10 1200,100 '></polyline></g></svg>";
```

**index.component.html:**

```
<tr style="height: 40px; position: relative !important;" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + svgBackgrounds + ')'}">
```

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Comment: You'll probably need to at least do `encodeURI()` on the SVG. Or Base64 encode it.  Other than that it will be hard to tell you more without a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem :) @PaulLeBeau